# Decimal values not rounded properly

Tags: c#-3.0, decimal, currency

I have some decimal(18, 2) fields in my SQL Express database.

Now when some aggregates happens to get a result. I sometimes lose 1 cent.

Say the result should be 192,84 euros my program shows 192,83 euros but if you make the aggregates with a calculator shows 192,84.

Any idea why this could happening. I use DevExpress controls with format string currency.
I have an idea changing the fields to decimal(18,3) what do u think?

Thank you

[EDIT]

Now when the values are suming for the first time shows (e.g. 1.074,64 as 1.074,65) that said I can see it rounds down but the correct is the 2nd ends ,65.

Example: 194,61 + 182,20 + 697,84 = 1.074,65, but it downs to 1.074,64. If you try get these values again it will show correctly....

Do you think I should round up always? What is the most better round up method for decimal values?

Some Code:

```
SumingTotal = AnObject.ListOfAType.Sum(p => p.DecimalProperty) +
                                                (DecimalValue1 + DecimalValue2);
```

Should equal to 1.074,65 but shows 1.074,64 if i get out of the environment showing these
values and try to check them again after some save in the database and recalculate while entering in the form shows correctly but in database is already wrong.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

How is the data stored in the database? Float?

If it's money, store it as decimal(18,2).

EDIT:
What is "ValuesDecimals"? If you say SELECT SUM(myfield) and myfiled is 18,3 then it will be correct.

It sounds like you're summing with "ValuesDecimals", which might be the source of the error.

Try showing the complete code?

Comment: I am storing it on database fields with type of decimal(18, 2) I don't get it.

Comment: Hello I have managed and detailed some code and the exact problem scenario

Comment: It was just a pseudocode, sorry for misunderstand...ValueDecimals is a List<T> where contains a EuroValue decimal property where I summing. Nothing really special. The decimal is (18, 2) in the database. you think it would be appropriate to turn into (18, 3)? I use Linq To SQL and not ADO.NET, besides this happens in memory so it's Linq To Objects aggregations...

Comment: @george Difficult to tell without all the code, but you're getting rounding errors, which means there *must* be a conversion away from 18,2 to something imprecise. Just moving to 18,3 is only going to hide the underlying problem, which you really need to find or all your accounting will be wrong.